# Missing nested array of struct object after json unmarshaling

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct, unmarshalling

I ran into some problem with unmarshalling string back to struct object when the object has a nested array of struct objects. I use the following code as a demo for my problem:

The json string is

```
const myStr = `{
  "name": "test_session1",
  "shared_items:": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": ".aspnet"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": ".bash_profile"
    }
  ]
}`
```

I have two structs as following with **Session** being the parent and **SharedItem** being the associated child(ren):

```
type Session struct {
    ID              uint64           `json:"id"`
    Name            string           `json:"name,omitempty"`
    SharedItems     []SharedItem `json:"shared_items"`
}

type SharedItem struct {
    ID          uint64 `json:"id"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
}
```

I tried the following to unmarshal the json string, but it looks like the nested array of **SharedItem** objects are missing, as I saw **sess** object has **0** shared items, which is not what I expected.

```
func main() {
    var sess Session
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(myStr), &sess); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("sess name is: %s, and has %d shared items\n", sess.Name, len(sess.SharedItems)) // printed: sess name is test_session1, and has 0 shared items
}
```

Here's the link to my go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/a-y5T3tut6g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Golang Spec for json unmarshal describe it all

> To unmarshal JSON into a struct, Unmarshal matches incoming object
>   keys to the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its
>   tag), preferring an exact match but also accepting a case-insensitive
>   match. By default, object keys which don't have a corresponding struct
>   field are ignored (see Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields for an
>   alternative).

In the json provided the json object for shared items has `:` colon in it as we can see it is `shared_items:` not `shared_items` which is our json tag

```
  "shared_items:": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": ".aspnet"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": ".bash_profile"
    }
  ]
```

Either remove `:` or append into your struct json tag to match the same.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Session struct {
    Name            string           `json:"name,omitempty"`
    SharedItems     []SharedItem    `json:"shared_items"`
}

type SharedItem struct {
    ID          uint64 `json:"id"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
}

const myStr = `{"name":"test_session1","shared_items":[{"id":0,"name":".aspnet"},{"id":1,"name":".bash_profile"}]}`

func main() {
    var sess Session

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(myStr), &sess); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(sess)
    fmt.Printf("sess name is: %s, and has %d shared items\n", sess.Name, len(sess.SharedItems))
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/s9IsUh9wC9s)

Comment: thanks, it turned to be a typo with the colon accidentally added after `shared_items`.

Comment: for unmarshalling json struct tags should match exactly with the json objects